# Asking question using Present past tense

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, questions, past-simple

I have confusion in asking question like, If I want to ask about *Tea* came or not.

- Is Tea came
- Did Tea come

Which one is correct or both wrong? Is there any other way to ask it.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to ask such a question would be:

> Has tea come (yet)?

But it would also be perfectly idiomatic to ask:

> Is tea coming (soon)?
>   Has tea been served?
>   Is tea ready (yet)?
>   When/What time is tea served?
>   (Is there) any sign of tea? (very informal)

To ask **is tea came** is neither idiomatic nor correct English.

To ask **did tea come** is possible and likely in certain contexts. In most situations, if you were asking someone whether tea had already been served, native English speakers would probably ask **has tea come/been served**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very informative.